# ng-multiselect-dropdown getting fired always

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, multi-select

I am using the ng-multiselect-dropdown. I am having an issue with one of the callbacks

```
     <ng-multiselect-dropdown *ngIf="filteredSids.length > 0"
                                         [data]="filteredSids"
                                         [disabled]="false"
                                         [(ngModel)]="selectedSids"
                                         (onSelect)="selectedSIDs($event); onItemSelect($event)"
                                         (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                                         (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                                         (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)"
                                         [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                                         (onDropDownClose)="onCloseDialog($event)">
                </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

The onDropDownClose callback getting fired not only when the drop down dismisses but when I click anywhere in the page. Its getting fired even if the dropdown is in dismissed state. I do need to get this fired only when the dropdown dismisses. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create the issue in stackblitz with minimal reproducible code?

Comment: @Joseph have you got any luck on this?

Comment: @djavaphp in fact NO!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, If anyone fixed it please help.